# Wiring patch panel for CAT6 wiring questions

Tags: networking, wiring

I have all cables just hanging off the ceiling. So, I got wall mount rack (8RU), 2 panels (24 each)

Now I have couple questions:

Is there standard/common height where I need to mound rack?

Ceiling is drop ceiling. I want to use 3in square plastic channels for wire coming down. Will it be OK to just notch tile 3x3 and have those channels go through?

Electricians who did wiring installed all terminations and wall jacks. They also numbered them. I initially thought I will wire panel first, number panel and then put corresponding numbers on wall jacks. But now I need to find wires in a loom and install them in order which will cause twisting and just not comfortable. Or should I just wire as it seems easier and then number on a patch panel?

If you have similar setup (wall mount rack to terminate cat6), can you post pics on how it's done?

Comment: I imagine this will get migrated or something, but there's no standard height you have to put it at - I would just make sure it's in an insulated area. As far as numbering them afterwards or finding out which cable is which - that is 100% up to how much effort you want to put into it. Ideally you would never need to troubleshoot any of your cables/connections - but if you do need to, it can be as simple as seeing which drop is having issues and removing a cable at a time (from patch to switch) until you find out which goes to which drop

Comment: With regards to wire order, It is 100% up to you. You can order them so they are grouped by wall plate, floor section, or whatever floats your boat. It would beneficial to use a tone generator tool to identify wires faster, though I am not sure if you are in the budget for another tool.

Comment: _Is there standard/common height where I need to mount rack?_ Above 4' from floor would be problematic for a short electrician. 

_Will it be OK to just notch tile 3x3 and have those channels go through?_ Yes IF the cable is plenum rated. If not, they will require conduit, as non-plenum cable has flammable plastic sleeves.

Comment: @Andy I only have LAN cable tester to make sure pinouts good. Thats a problem. See, I was going to put them on a rack as 1-2-3 and then while wiring at wall plate just put correct numbers there. Now, with wall plates in place it's kind of PITA